# Java generics with several values

Tags: java, generics

It has been a long time since I haven't written any Java and I get pretty confused with the `<String, Integer>` in the following line (from the following [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-pardo)):

`static class ComputeWordLengthFn extends DoFn<String, Integer> { ... }`

I am not even sure that it is the generics concept that occurs here.

What should I understand regarding `String` and `Integer` here?

Documentation for DoFn: [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.html)

Comment: What is `DoFn`?

Comment: Give the `DoFn` definition if you want a explaining about that.

Comment: Assuming you're looking at [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) (and, btw, it helps if you say what it is you are reading), `String` is the input type to a function and `Integer` is the result type. But in general, these could mean absolutely anything.

Comment: @AndyTurner I just updated my post to provide documentation. You seem to be right indeed, input and output. How is this annotation called? This isn't generics right?